# Выполнение 2-ух запросов к БД в одном условие

Tags: php, sql

Всем привет. Возникла небольшая проблема, необходимо выполнить 2 запроса к базе данных. Первый запрос создает диалог, второй создает сообщение к этому диалогу, но непонятно по какой причине второй запрос с созданием сообщения в БД не выполняется, а просто игнорируется.

```
        if (isset($_POST['sendls'])) {

        $dialog = $db->getObject("SELECT * FROM dialog where user1=$id or user2=$id");
        $lstext = $_POST['lstext'];


        if (isset($dialog)) {
            $db->execute("
                    INSERT INTO personalmessage (text, users_id, dialog_id) VALUES ('$lstext', $users_id, $dialog->id)
                ");
        } else {
            $db->execute("
                INSERT INTO dialog (user1, user2) VALUES ($users_id, $id);
            ");

            $db->execute("
                    INSERT INTO personalmessage (text, users_id, dialog_id) VALUES ('$lstext', $users_id, $id)
                ");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Анализируйте код возврата и код ошибки. Ну можете заодно посмотреть General log на предмет того, добираются ли запросы до сервера, и если да, то в каком виде.

Comment: А почему в последнем insert вы вставляете в поле dialog_id переменную $id, которая в предыдущем запросе идет в поле user2. как так получается, что у пользователя и диалога один и тот же id ?

Comment: @Mike Благодарю) Как раз тут то я и не доглядел, исправил, все заработало. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в неправильно сформулированном запросе, а именно неправильно указывался ID созданного диалога. Спасибо @Mike за ответ.